# Ruby CSV separates numbers by a comma and is not escaping it

Tags: ruby, excel, csv

When I generate a csv file in Ruby, the Ruby CSV library is separating out the numbers based on its thousands comma. For example numbers such $5.00 stay in their own cell, while numbers like $257,000,415.81 will instead be surrounded in double quotes and get split up on the thousands comma into the next cell. example ("$257 | 000 | 415.81"). The csv parses the number correctly as long as it is not the first value. How do I get the csv library to properly format the number in the same cell? The program i'm using to open the csv file is Microsoft Excel.

Here is a screen shot of how the text looks in excel.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EMs0.png

And here is a screen shot of how I would like the text to look.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/opjrR.png

Below is the code for the csv.

```
<%= CSV.generate_line(["Balance"]).strip %>
 <% @accounts.each do |acct| %>
    <% row = [
      (number_to_currency acct.balance, :unit => "$")
    ] %>
 <%= CSV.generate_line(row).strip.html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Read "[mcve]". It's important we be able to duplicate the problem. Show us minimal example input and the output you expect.

Comment: What does the actual data look like? That's more important than what it looks like in Excel. It's not clear to me why you're generating each line of CSV in ERB. Let the CSV library generate the entire file. There's no need for ERB here, and using both is an invitation for issues.

Comment: You only show the partial code for the CSV.  How is the CSV file created, and what options are provided to it?  How are the headers written?  Please show *complete* code for your example.

Comment: You can use double quotes around the numbers to keep them from getting split on `,` by setting the option `force_quotes: true` and then escaping those quotes with a backslash like this: `\"`. But as pointed out above you are still not giving nearly enough info for a solid answer.

Comment: I tried to add additional screen shots to how the data is appearing to me in excel. Its quite clear that the numbers are getting separated on the comma thousands line. All i'm really asking for is a way to escape the thousands comma and have the number values all together in one cell.

Answer (score 0):

This should work to create the CSV file correctly:

```
CSV.open('filename.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  @accounts.each do |acct|
    csv << [ number_to_currency(acct.balance, unit: '$') ]
  end
end
```

Comment: Getting "undefined method `find' " when I try to use row.to_csv. Doesn't seem to work even when I require the Csv library at the top of the line

Comment: You are right! I fixed it now - and tested it this time. Cheers!